# how to know if the registration was successful

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase's realtime database. When you register, it returns some values. Some of these values ​​say if the registration was successful or not ??

```
// Register category
function register() {
    let form = document.querySelector("#modalCategory form");
    let submitBtn = document.querySelector("#modalCategory form button");

    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let data = getData();

        let result = realtimedb_register("Categories", data);
        console.log(result);
    })

    function getData() {
        let data = {
            category: categoryTitleInput.value
        }
        return data;
    }
}register()

// Register or create data
function realtimedb_register(db, data) {
    return firebase.database().ref(db).push(data);
}
```

returned value:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `push()` returns a promise, so you can wait for that to resolve:

```
let result = realtimedb_register("Categories", data);
result.then(() => {
  console.log("Database write completed");
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log("Database write failed", error);
})
```

If you don't like the look of the `then()` and `catch()`, you can use [`await` and `async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) as syntactic sugar.